# Reputation is bouncing around

Tags: bug, reputation, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Something is going wrong with my reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144084/something-is-going-wrong-with-my-reputation)

My reputation has been bouncing around for the past hour or so. I had 1350 rep at about 1 PM today, which mysteriously dropped to 1346. I couldn't find anything to account for it. I figured it was just 4 points, who cares. But now I just made an edit, and it went up to 1352. But when I reloaded the page, it dropped to 1348. What's going on?

[image]

I went and checked my rep using https://stackoverflow.com/reputation to try to find out what was up.

```
 2  11677558 (10)
 3  11677557 (-2)
 3  11677558 (-2)
 3  11677557 (-2)
 2  11677558 (10)
 2  10656280 (10)
 2  11512708 (10)
 16 11692438 (2)
 2  11420263 (5)
 16 11693190 (2)
 2  11677558 (10)
-- 2012-07-27 rep +53   = 1346
```

[image]

After my edit.

[image]

After a page refresh.

[image]

Made another edit

[image]

And another page refresh

[image]

Comment: Did you check for removed posts (on the reputation page, check the checkbox near the page bottom, "show removed posts").

Comment: Yes. Nothing was out of place.

Comment: Isn't the `-4` due to the two downvotes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677557/what-are-binary-trees-and-why-are-they-useful?)?

Comment: That happened last night. Like 20 hours ago. It's the fact that any increase in rep yields +4 more rep than it should, and disappears on a page refresh.

Comment: To cope with this, you should play House of Pain - Jump Around in the background while puzzling over your reputation history.

Comment: Sounds like the live refresh doesn't know about your two downvotes yet. Is it only showing the +4 values when you leave the page sit and let it auto-update?

Comment: @animuson It's known about it all day. Only recently did it start doing this. Like last night, I watched the reputation go away. But yes, I let auto update show my new rep.

Comment: How quickly were your edits approved? Your last approved edit took [4 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/332281), the one before that [15 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/332272). So you would not get rep for that right away. (Also [some were rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/users/868546/drise?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), hence not giving you any reputation at all. Hover the timestamps to see exact times.) And this is not related by your suggested edits for the Python question that clashed with other edits twice? (Beware when editing in the grace period.)

Comment: @Arjan, that isn't what I'm pointing out.

Comment: So then the summary is "Live update increases reputation before suggested edits are approved"? If so, then please change the title?

Comment: @Arjan. No. Still not it. I had 1350 rep. 4 disappeared for no reason. On any gain of rep, the come back, and on page refresh they vanish. Edits are just an easy way to get some rep.

Comment: So, I let it go over the weekend, and it's still doing it.

Comment: If it still happens can you monitor the network traffic and see what the live refresh is getting from the server? Not sure it's possible as it's using web sockets but worth a try. :)

Comment: @Drise Does this issue occur when you gain reputation from other source? (i.e. upvote). I have the [same issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144084/something-is-going-wrong-with-my-reputation) but with upvote.