# Something is going wrong with my reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, live-refresh

Whenever I gain reputation, I get 4 additional reputation. See this picture:

[image]

This picture is captured when I gained reputation by +5 (for upvote on my question.). Before I gain +5 reputation, my reputation was **2,211**. And after I gained +5 reputation, my reputation became **2,220** (as shown in the above picture). But when I refresh my page the real reputation is shown like this:

[image]

So the problem is minor. But why do this happen? I suspect this issue might be related with [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142810/getting-2-reputation-for-suggested-edit-even-after-reaching-1000-rep-boundary).

**EDIT:** I do not face this issue in the case of downvotes.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [Reputation is bouncing around](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141432/reputation-is-bouncing-around). Do you only see this for live updates of your reputation?

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. Someone doesn't agree with something in your post, don't worry about it.

Comment: I agree with @Arjan this is a bug with live refresh, as you said yourself reloading the page "fix" it and there's no trace for the problem in the reputation tab, right?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Right.

Comment: Guess you got downvote because unlike in the other question you didn't post much details.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question. I also had an issue, after reaching 1000 rep. cap for suggested edit, whenever I suggest edit and it approved, I get +2 for that. And next day it is removed.

Comment: @Arjan: The pending suggestions queue is never long these days; his most recent suggestions were all approved very quickly; I doubt there are any pending suggested edits old enough left..

Comment: @Arjan Now, I can not suggest edit.

Comment: Just a thought: maybe the reputation as used in the live update is counting approved edits on posts that have meanwhile been deleted? Not sure if one is to keep that reputation to start with, but I guess not. Also, it's not very likely that the live update makes its own calculations of the reputation...

Comment: @Arjan Side question, How could you know that user ([Drise](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186397/drise)) has 152 suggested edits?

Comment: @hims056 http://stackoverflow.com/users/868546/drise?tab=activity&sort=suggestions :)

Comment: @Arjan you think the live refresh read the reputation from a different source?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I would not expect that, but given this and other questions that show a different value on refresh, it seems like it? Odd, for sure.

Comment: @Arjan odd indeed, but I assume it's some "zombie reputation events" that the live refresh is getting somehow.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with those trivial edits?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I just corrected grammatical errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We love to instantly notify people of the positive activities that happen.  When somebody loves the things you do you are instantly notified by a reputation increase.  The negative - well, you get to know about it but it's not as instant.  We assume those with a negativity need to have a bit of time to evaluate their decision before that choice is made known.  We also try to protect people who down vote from being discovered.

We call it the broken unicorn syndrome:  http://www.ted.com/talks/shawn_achor_the_happy_secret_to_better_work.html

Comment: Any chance to explain this in simpler terms?

Comment: Just so I understand: are you saying that the live update is ignoring *existing* downvotes for some time, even though the regular reputation display does not? So, say I have 100 rep, then get downvoted to get at 98, and then some time later get +10, that live update makes my displayed rep go from 98 to 110, rather than 108? (And then a refresh makes it 108 after all?)

Comment: No, you should see 108.

Comment: Er, then the OP's *"Whenever I gain reputation"* is false? Sounds to me like it's *always* showing 4 too many for the OP.

Comment: @Geoff with the new top bar this appears to be more simple: the live counter show the amount of reputation gained since it was last clicked. If that amount is negative it just won't show any number at all. Is this correct?