# Reputation counter in top bar acting up?

Tags: bug, reputation, live-refresh

Something weird seems to be going on with the reputation counter at the top of the page, next to the username: Several times today I saw the counter at an unusually high value, but when I clicked it, my actual reputation was lower. Right Now I can see "145,318" in one of my tabs, though my cap won't actually allow more than 145,300 for today. As soon as I reload, the counter is back to the correct value, but the live view seems to overshoot (usually after I answer a question).

Comment: 1+ I have been noticing this too - today only.

Comment: +1 I've experienced this consistently.

Comment: I've seen something similar, but, in my case, it looked like accepted answers and votes which were then retracted (it mainly appears to be 10 or 15).

Comment: Saturday is laundry day at SE.  Front page and tag page views have been acting strange again as well.

Comment: @Dukeling: At first I thought it was an upvote that had been retracted shortly after, but now that this made my counter go over the cap I know for sure it's not just up- and unupvotes...

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, accepted answers aren't affected by the cap. But, taking into account the cap, 18 doesn't seem to fit particularly well into my theory. Maybe the cap got it all confused.

Comment: @Dukeling: The 18 includes a downvote. Right now that tab says 145,320 (I haven't reloaded it), but the actual value is 145,300...

Comment: I guess that whenever you get an upvote, the live refresh detects it and show the change instantly (+5 or +10) without checking for rep cap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something is going wrong with my reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144084/something-is-going-wrong-with-my-reputation)

Comment: @hims056: I'm not sure this is a duplicate. I've been on this site for a while, and I'm aware of the various "instant" features, but I have never noticed this particular phenomenon before yesterday.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Instant rep updates have been around for a long time, and I'm aware of those. But I have never seen the distinct "overshooting" before yesterday.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, it happens only after you reach the rep cap, maybe you just didn't notice before? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: No... what's happening here is that the counter goes *above* the real value. This has never happened before. Up till now, the instant counter used to show the correct value, and it had always respected the cap.

Comment: @KerrekSB I still think it's the same issue reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144084/152859) but of course might be wrong. Hopefully dev will check into this.