# New Rep indicator stops when having negative score

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, top-bar

Today I gave a [bounty of 500 rep to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156761/add-a-hint-to-stay-put-after-posting-a-question).

This results of course in a negative score for today.

Since then I don't get any more notifications for new rep in the new top-bar on meta.

[image: rep history]

Only after resetting the rep indicator by clicking on it I get new notifications.

Comment: I have noticed interesting behavior surrounding negative rep as well.

Comment: Yeah, it's showing net change since you last clicked it and programmed to never show negative number. Try clicking it now and it should show new rep gaining. :)

Comment: I clicked there. Now I wait for someone to upvote me :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yep. Now I get notifications again.

Comment: @juergend so I fear [meta-tag:status-bydesign] is due here. The team doesn't want to show negative numbers in there.

Comment: Yeah. I don't find that intiutive. I don't click on that indicator if no new rep shows up.

Comment: Another good reason to [show the negative rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/show-negative-reputation). It would just always show all activity. This would be so much more meaningful..

Comment: Worth to mention [broken unicorn syndrome](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144145/152859) - unless something changed during the last year I don't think they will change the current behavior. @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd FYI as well.

Comment: I made a proposal to work around this problem: [Ignore the rep change caused by bounties in the achievements reputation indicator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209467/ignore-the-rep-change-caused-by-bounties-in-the-acheivements-indicator-calculati)

Answer (score 10):

I'm wondering why this is status by design?

I know we don't get notified on negative rep etc, but we do get notified on positive rep.
Why would our losing a load of rep on a bounty (or anything) affect the positive rep notifications coming through after that?

Positive rep following loss from placing a bounty is positive rep. The loss from the bounty changes one's total rep, and any rep earned from there on in is positive and surely should be notified of?

This is precisely when users will want to know they are getting more rep in so they can see they're getting their bounty back.

(just saying, like...)

Comment: The thing is the achievements box has its own internal "reputation counter". When you click the icon (or hover it while other box is open) the counter will reset to 0. When the counter is >0 you'll see it, otherwise it won't show. You will indeed see it decreasing e.g. when getting downvotes. Asking to make it show negative number (better with different color, likely red) makes some sense, feel free to start such feature request. :)