# Why do reputation drops not highlight the Achievements icon?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

The "Recent achievements" icon doesn't highlight when one only has recent reputation losses.

I'd like it to highlight whenever my reputation changes, positive or negative - in fact I'd suggest it's far more important for me to review posts that get a downvote than those that got an upvote.

Is there a reason negative reputation events don't cause it to highlight?

Comment: The graph icon shows a drop in the fourth position.  Not that this implies anything of course...

Comment: It is a long standing design decision - we don't give real time notification of _negative_ things.

Comment: @iStimple So then why are negative rep events still shown inside the Achievements dropdown?

Comment: More discussion: [Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements)

Comment: @Oded how come bounty is negative thing?

Comment: You lose reputation, @Sha.

Comment: @Oded true, but bounty is a positive action, not negative. Maybe have the counter ignore rep loss due to bounty, i.e. getting an upvote after starting a bounty will bring the +5/+10 even if I did not click the icon?

Comment: Not a bad idea. [meta-tag:feature-request]? @Sha

Comment: @Oded never too late, but turns out there is [already such a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209467/ignore-the-rep-change-caused-by-placing-bounties-in-the-achievements-reputation?lq=1). If you can do anything about it (even just poking the team from the inside) it would be great. :-)

Answer (score -23, accepted):

We want to let you know about good things as soon as they happen - that's what our real-time notifications are for.

Negative reputation changes are... well... negative. So we are not in a hurry to let you know about them.

Comment: So for users interested in improving questions that receive downvotes, there's no notification for them, by design? Seems like a gap to me.

Comment: @AdamDavis - What's the immediacy? The information is one click away, in the achievement dropdown, even if not highlighted in a notification.

Comment: Your question suggests that reputation increases have more immediate value than decreases, but a little critical thinking should demonstrate the opposite.  Posts receiving downvotes need more immediate attention than those receiving upvotes. I, in fact, *want* notices on all voting activity, but right now don't get such notice for reputation loss, nor community wiki upvotes/downvotes of any kind - those don't even show up in the box.

Comment: But isn't the rep loss from posting a bounty a negative change with an inherently positive connotation? (Same with downvoting answers or deleting your own posts, but those aren't as confusing as [the bounty issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313628/mark-rep-loss-from-posting-a-bounty-as-seen-automatically))

Comment: This is terrible logic because it's a change to our reputation, and we need to be notified of changes to our status immediately. Please revert that decision so that we are always notified of a reputation change @Oded

Comment: @TylerH - this was an early design decision - long before I started working at SO. I don't expect it will be changed, however unpopular it is (fact is - they rep change *shows* in the dropdown, it just isn't notified)

Comment: I just find the reasoning of "we don't want you to know when bad stuff happens to you", well, basically indefensible. Were the implementers afraid of *hurting our feelings* or what? It's leading to some [really](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209467/ignore-the-rep-change-caused-by-placing-bounties-in-the-achievements-reputation) [confusing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313628/mark-rep-loss-from-posting-a-bounty-as-seen-automatically) [situations](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294486/reputation-losses-hide-future-gains-in-the-top-bar) (that's 3 separate links, btw)

Comment: @Oded can it make configurable, so that the user can deside if he will see downvotes or not? Think that will be better design.

Comment: @Jens - that would be an additional check on every single page load. And a setting that would be used by a very very very small number of people. It is not worth doing.

Comment: This is terrible reasoning. Positive changes might make somebody *happy* but negative changes are more *important* because they indicate something that you might want to address. The purpose of the indicator shouldn't be some kind of pleasure-centre stimulant. It should be to notify you of important events. Negative events are at least as important, if not more so.

Answer (score 12):

> I'd suggest it's far more important for me to review posts that get a downvote than those that got an upvote.

I quite agree. A downvote could mean there is something wrong with your post such as being off-topic, inappropriate, abusive etc. etc., that requires a bit more attention than the extra 10 rep an upvote gives you.

Oded said

> Negative reputation changes are... well... negative. So we are not in a hurry to let you know about them.

I heartily disagree. You should know about them as soon as possible, for the same reasons I gave above.

So no, I don't think there is a reason, but there should be one.  If this is by design, it really shouldn't be.