# Wrong association bonus point number shown while joining Space Exploration community

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog, association-bonus

Recently I had joined to [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/) community. Though I have receive 100 association bonus point, wrong number was shown as notification.

[image: Association bonus on joining Space Exploration Community.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you had lost 33 reputation prior to gaining this association bonus. See [Why do reputation drops not highlight the Achievements icon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219652)

The reason the loss of that 33 reputation is not shown in the dialog is because it's lost via a post deletion, and deleted posts don't show up in the achievements dialog.

It's not a bug indeed. I am expecting [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Better mention this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219652/why-do-reputation-drops-not-highlight-the-achievements-icon

Comment: @ShadowtheWelcomingWizard Yeah thanks for the heads up!