# 14 badge notifications without receiving the badge

Tags: bug, badges, notifications

[image]

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209467/ignore-the-rep-change-caused-by-placing-bounties-in-the-achievements-reputation/244172#244172) just received a couple upvotes, bringing it to 10. I just got 14 badge notifications for this post. However, it doesn't even show up once in my [list of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=259693).