# Inconsistent reputation showing on profile

Tags: bug, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation is bouncing around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141432/reputation-is-bouncing-around)

A few minutes ago I went to my profile and noticed -10 on my tab header, though this action is not found on the flyout or on the reputation list.

I imagine this is a case of one area being updated before or after another, but there is no way to tell what this was. Almost certainly a quick upvote/unupvote, but how can I know?

Not that being off by one is a big deal, and it is only a transient issue. But can we make a better effort at live updates being applied consistently across all areas of a single page?

[image]

Comment: Don't worry - you'll still be over 200 with out those 10 points ;)

Comment: Oh I know, the rep itself isn't my concern. It's just confusing to have indications on one part of the screen that aren't substantiated in other parts, where they should match...

Comment: Does your reputation page show changes caused from deleted posts too?

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes, "show removed posts" is always checked.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141432/reputation-is-bouncing-around. Note also: It stops after a while.

Comment: @Drise thanks, yes it is definitely transient. But I see it enough that I know it happens a lot.

Comment: Have you tried a rep-recalc?

Comment: @Drise rep recalc shouldn't be required these days. Also my rep seems right now. It was just temporarily showing -10 for some reason.

Comment: That's the advice that was given to me, though it didn't do anything. Doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Drise rep recalc did not change anything.

Comment: Meh, didn't think so.

Comment: It's weird, it seems to "catch up" after some time.

Comment: Yeah, I see this too sometimes. It's transient, lasts only a few minutes when it happens.

Comment: You seem to have a favorite star next to your name in your profile... what's that about?

Comment: @PopularDemand it's a plug-in that lets me mark other users as favorites. This applies slightly different styling to their comments, questions and answers. This isn't the URL I used but I believe it's the same one. http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/Stack-Exchange-Favorite-Users.shtml